# Postgres Error while fetching data from the access_log table

Tags: postgresql

**Error :** column **access_log.id** must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function] when the subquery is used

```
select
    to_char(date_trunc('day',create_time),'DD MON, YYYY') as create_time,
    to_char((max(create_time) - min(create_time)),'HH24:mi') as time_spent,
    id
from 
    access_log
group by
    user_id, actionlink_id, date_trunc('day',create_time)
```

Comment: you group by user_id, actionlink_id and select id?.. what do you try to achieve?..

Comment: I want to send id to the next page, that's why I want to return id

Comment: please give some short data sample and expected result for your aggregation

Comment: id should return the integer value

Comment: I have used MAX and MIN in a query, those are the  aggregate functions

Comment: please give some short data sample and expected result for your aggregation

Comment: Please explain what `"I want to send id to the next page"` means. You are running a query where **each row is a summary combining data of many id's**.  So how can it also show id? which id is relevant? the `maximum(id)?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`access_log.id` is unique for each row in that table, so it is very unlikely that you get useful information including that in the query. I believe you intended to do this by `user_id` instead. However what the error message is telling you the truth, **IF** you include `id` in the `select clause`, it should also occur in the `group by` clause. read on:

Think of each item in your `select clause` as falling into 2 types:

1. **aggregating** these are the ones with `MIN` `MAX` `COUNT` `AVG` and similar functions
2. **non-aggregating** these are the ones without thse functions, and it is these that determine how rows are formed. **Each one of these non-aggregating items should appear in the group by clause.** This information in these columns is then used to create the row structure of the final result. For example instead of rows for each time of the day, now rows will be "per day" because you included `date_trunc('day',create_time)` into the `group by` clause

```
select
      user_id ---- changed this to user_id
    , actionlink_id  --- & added this 
    , to_char(date_trunc('day',create_time),'DD MON, YYYY') as create_time

    , to_char((max(create_time) - min(create_time)),'HH24:mi') as time_spent
    , MAX(id) as max_id
from 
    access_log
group by -- all non-aggregating select clause items go here
    user_id
  , actionlink_id
  , date_trunc('day',create_time)
```